# Count occurrence of each unique element in an array using ES5

Tags: javascript, unique, frequency, ecmascript-5

I am using AngularJS and there is a use case where I have a list of user objects similar to this

```
[{
  name: 'name1',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name3',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name1',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  age: 21
}]
```

I need to calculate the frequency of each unique element and store in an object so that it is easy to iterate through using ng-repeat.

Object:

```
{
  name: 'name1',
  count: 2
},
{
  name: 'name3,
  count: 1
}
```

Using ES6, it's easy, but not supported by IE11 as I am using AngularJS.

Hence, looking for an efficient solution in ES5.

Comment: are you consider using polyfill babel?

Comment: Do you have any key which is guaranteed to be unique? And how do you want to compare - by all the keys, or just by name? Example: if 2 people have same name and age, then only one of them gets to be in the array?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `forEach()` and use a map to map name with their counts.

```js
var arr =[{ name: 'name1', age: 21 }, { name: 'name2', age: 21 }, { name: 'name3', age: 21 }, { name: 'name1', age: 21 }, { name: 'name2', age: 21 }];
var map = {};
var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(a){
  if(!map[a.name]){
    map[a.name] ={
      "name" : a.name,
      "count" : 0
    }
    result.push(map[a.name]);
  }
  map[a.name].count++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object as helper for generating an array as result.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'name1', age: 21 }, { name: 'name2', age: 21 }, { name: 'name3', age: 21 }, { name: 'name1', age: 21 }, { name: 'name2', age: 21 }],
    temp = Object.create(null),
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (!temp[o.name]) {
            r.push(temp[o.name] = { name: o.name, count: 0 });
        }
        temp[o.name].count++;
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or take a two step approach

```js
var data = [{ name: 'name1', age: 21 }, { name: 'name2', age: 21 }, { name: 'name3', age: 21 }, { name: 'name1', age: 21 }, { name: 'name2', age: 21 }],
    temp = Object.create(null),
    result;

data.forEach(function (o) {
    temp[o.name] = (temp[o.name] || 0) + 1;
});

result = Object.keys(temp).map(function (k) {
    return { name: k, count: temp[k] };
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [{
  name: 'name1',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name3',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name1',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  age: 21
}]

var dictionary = {};
var result = [];
items.forEach(function(a){
  if(dictionary[a.name])
  {
   dictionary[a.name].count++;
  }else
  {
   dictionary[a.name] = {
      "name" : a.name,
      "count" : 1
    }
    result.push(dictionary[a.name]);
  }
 
});

console.log(result);
```